# Smarty 3.1 shows blank ouput

Tags: php, smarty

I have updated my smarty to 3.1 but it is not showing me any output.page simply blank .But same code working for smarty 2. What is reason for that

Comment: Different versions means different code ... 
you must migrate your code!

Comment: Turn on debug output in your php and look at the errors produced by smarty.

Comment: Did you retain folder structure on server? In case you created some new folders (esp for compiled templates), you may have not set their access rights properly (must be rw for compiled templates, r for other folders).

Comment: everything is set correct but it shows blank page. when i remove the below code then it shows output page. but same code works on smarty 2
intApPayeePropertyId ={/literal}{$ap_payee_property_id}{literal};